# Multi item select feature in Angular4 drag and drop

Tags: angular

I am working on angular4 and I have requirement where I need to implement drag and drop feature with multiple items selected. I have used `ng2-drag-drop` and `dragula`  , but these allow to drag and drop a single item . Is there any way I implement drag and drop in angular4 with multi item select feature?

Comment: Did you found a solution?